# My count_vote() functions works ones only

Tags: php, mysqli

The function count_vote() is used to count the votes collected from a form and stored in a database.

```
function count_vote($result ,$Q_X){
        $res = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        while ($report = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($report[$Q_X] == 'X1') {
                $res[0] = $res[0] + 1;

            } elseif ($report[$Q_X] == 'X2') {
                $res[1] = $res[1] + 1;

            } elseif ($report[$Q_X] == 'X3') {
                $res[2] = $res[2] + 1;

            } elseif ($report[$Q_X] == 'X4') {
                $res[3] = $res[3] + 1;

            } elseif ($report[$Q_X] == 'X5') {
                $res[4] = $res[4] + 1;
            }
        }
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1) {
            return $res;
        }
    }
```

The user answers four Questions with five text answers like this.

```
   text |  very good  |  good  |  works  |  bad  | very bad
   value|  X1         |  X2    |  X3     |  X4   | X5
```

the answers are collected in the database with this format

```
        |  Q1   |  Q2   |   Q3   |   Q4   |
user1   |  X1   |  X3   |   X5   |   X4   |
user2   |  X2   |  X2   |   X3   |   X2   |
user3   |  X1   |  X1   |   X1   |   X1   |
```

what I was expecting from count_vote()

```
Question     answer   count
Q1           X1       2
Q1           X2       1
Q1           X3       0
Q1           X4       0
Q1           X4       0
Q2           X1       2
Q2           X2       1
Q2           X3       0
Q2           X4       0
Q2           X4       0
```

for Q3,Q4 also

The result i got

the count_vote() function worked for the first Question but not for the rest of the Questions

```
Question     answer   count
Q1           X1       2
Q1           X2       1
Q1           X3       0
Q1           X4       0
Q1           X4       0
Q2           X1       0
Q2           X2       0
Q2           X3       0
Q2           X4       0
Q2           X4       0
```

for Q3,Q4 also

what i used to display the result

```
list($Q1_1, $Q1_2, $Q1_3, $Q1_4, $Q1_5) = count_vote($result ,"Q1");

  echo $Q1_1 . ',';
  echo $Q1_2 . ',';
  echo $Q1_3 . ',';
  echo $Q1_4 . ',';
  echo $Q1_5 . '<br>';


  list($Q2_1, $Q2_2, $Q2_3, $Q2_4, $Q2_5) = count_vote($result ,"Q2");

  echo $Q2_1 . ',';
  echo $Q2_2 . ',';
  echo $Q2_3 . ',';
  echo $Q2_4 . ',';
  echo $Q2_5 . '<br>';
```

for Q3,Q4 also

how i SELECT the data

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `ex`";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: Can you please print $result straight after this line "$result=mysqli_query($link, $query);"

Comment: `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 29 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 5 [type] => 0 )` @Perdeep Singh

Comment: also could you please print $report after this line "while ($report = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {"

Comment: if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1) {
            return $res;
        } is wrong as well why you checking $result here?

Comment: Sergey means that you should use X-debug and then in real time using bookmark you would be able to see execution to see what route your code takes and what values are getting set due to which conditions etc.

Comment: It checks if any rows are returned at all, otherwise, it will not try to give you any results because there are none.

Comment: Can you not check $res instead ?
if(count($res)){ return $res; }

Comment: it givs the same result `2,1,0,0,0`  

`0,0,0,0,0`

Comment: I got the feeling that your if conditions inside loop are creating trouble so you always getting initialised $res. Would you be able to convert $result into php array and print then I can use that to check your function.

Comment: `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 29 [lengths] => Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 11 [2] => 2 [3] => 4 [4] => 2 [5] => 2 [6] => 2 [7] => 2 [8] => 2 [9] => 2 [10] => 2 [11] => 2 [12] => 2 [13] => 2 [14] => 2 [15] => 2 [16] => 2 [17] => 2 [18] => 2 [19] => 0 [20] => 0 [21] => 0 [22] => 1 [23] => 2 [24] => 1 [25] => 1 [26] => 4 [27] => 1 [28] => 19 ) [num_rows] => 5 [type] => 0 )`

Comment: is this what you asked @Perdeep Singh

Comment: @Unheilig _Timo_,  _andrewsi_, _kamal pal_ and  _EdChum_ kindly check the question changes so to remove the down votes **if it meets the requirements**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please see below working solution of your problem:**

```
<?php

    include '../mysqCode/masterlink.php';
    mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `ex`";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $rows = [];
    while ($report = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = $report;
    }

    function count_vote($rows, $Q_X)
    {
        $res = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
        array_walk($rows, function ($row) use (&$res, $Q_X) {
            switch ($row[ $Q_X ]) {
                case 'X1':
                    $res[0] = $res[0] + 1;
                    break;
                case 'X2':
                    $res[1] = $res[1] + 1;
                    break;
                case 'X3':
                    $res[2] = $res[2] + 1;
                    break;
                case 'X4':
                    $res[3] = $res[3] + 1;
                    break;
                case 'X5':
                    $res[4] = $res[4] + 1;
                    break;
            }
        });

        return $res;
    }


    list($Q1_1, $Q1_2, $Q1_3, $Q1_4, $Q1_5) = count_vote($rows, "Q1");

    echo $Q1_1 . ',';
    echo $Q1_2 . ',';
    echo $Q1_3 . ',';
    echo $Q1_4 . ',';
    echo $Q1_5;


    list($Q2_1, $Q2_2, $Q2_3, $Q2_4, $Q2_5) = count_vote($rows, "Q2");

    echo $Q2_1 . ',';
    echo $Q2_2 . ',';
    echo $Q2_3 . ',';
    echo $Q2_4 . ',';
    echo $Q2_5 . '<br>';
```

***Explanation and reason wasn't working before***

`array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )`

Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and **moves the internal data pointer ahead**.

So when you call function 2nd time pointer is moved ahead and never trace each row again and as a result you always received $res=[0,0,0,0,0] after first run.

Comment: Thanks for your help. what  does, `MYSQLI_ASSOC` do and this one too `array_walk($rows, function ($row) use (&$res, $Q_X)`  -sorry for not  checking  your solution sooner the network connection was out-

Comment: MYSQLI_ASSOC fetch row as associative array so without it you will get result as array[ 0=>'X1', 'Q1'=>'X1'...] with MYSQLI_ASSOC you will only get array['Q1'=>'X1'.
About array walk it's cleaner way of avoiding foreach loop as it walks through each array item and closure function does any action needed to be done. So in short array walk doing what you were doing with while.
Hope it makes sense.

Comment: about use(&$res,$Q_X) all we doing here is passing external variables to closure function so it can have access to it else it will complain undefined variables. You would have noticed we passing $res as pass by reference instead of value so that inside array walk we can manipulate original $res instead of it's copy.

Answer (score 0):

Your function gets a $result as first argument.
It modifies $result during process :

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result)
```

So during the second run, the $result is at the end of the result set, there if no more data ...

I think it's a bad practice to have a `count_vote()` function with direct access to the database. You must separate concerns.

Or if you cant, rename your function `read_resultset_and_count_votes()` to avoid bad surprises ...